# Why is the PHP $_SERVER mixed with client and server values

Tags: php, http-headers

I just did a `print_r` on `$_SERVER`.
It contains `SCRIPT_FILENAME` which is known only on the receiving end, but it also has `HTTP_USER_AGENT` which came from the browser sending the form. 
Is there a way to separate the values?
For example, if I use the Google DevTools in Chrome, it's seperated into Response Headers and Request Headers.

Why are they grouped together in PHP and how can I seperate them?

Comment: All the server variables that begin with `HTTP_` come from the request headers. Everything else is from the server itself.

Answer (score 1):

That super global variable collects all technical details of interest available about the request. It is neither server nor client specific.

There is no automatic approach to separate those, since it is an arbitrary, hard coded collection. You can only create a dictionary yourself picking which values you connect with which side (which is ambiguous...). Take a look at the documentation for a list of all potential fields: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php